# Writing a SQL Statement Based on A Question

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to complete this homework problem but I keep getting an error.

Here is the problem:

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCFaB.jpg)

The query that I wrote is this:

```
Select vendor_id, invoice_total - payment_total - credit_total,
SUM(invoice_total - payment_total - credit_total) OVER() AS Total, 
SUM(invoice_total - payment_total - credit_total) OVER(partition by vendor_id) AS total_vendor_balance
From invoices
Where invoice_total - payment_total - credit_total > 0
```

And the error is this:

```
Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'ap.invoices.invoice_total' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: You're missing `GROUP BY vendor_id`.

Comment: I added that and it still gives me an error :(

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `invoice_total - payment_total - credit_total` outside the aggregates. Which row in the group should it return?

Comment: What I understanding from the picture is that it wants me to create a new calculation called balance due, by subtracting the three variables already in the table.